# what is the exact difference between signedcookies and unsignedcookies in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, cookies

Hai Everyone I'm beginner in Nodejs.I have tried **cookie-parser** module in express.They are setting the signed cookie using {signed:true}.

First of all clarify me.

1.why **should I use signed cookie**? and

2.what is the **use of signed cookie**?.

I have checked the solutions but No one said what is the use of it?.

I have tried both the cases separately in the program and I did not get any error for without using secret key and signed cookie :

Any help would be appreciate Thanks in advance...

Node code:

1. **using signed cookies with secret key**

```html
app.use(cookieparser("Youcansetanydataasasecret"));
const options={
    maxAge:1000*60*5,
    httpOnly:true,
    signed:true
};
app.get('/setcookie',(req,res)=>{
    res.cookie('cookieone','This is my first cookie',options);
    res.send(`Cookie has been set...`);
});
app.get('/readcookie',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.signedCookies['cookieone']);
    res.send(req.signedCookies['cookieone']);
});
```

2. **without using signed cookies and secret.**

```html
app.use(cookieparser());
const options={
    maxAge:1000*60*5,
    httpOnly:true,
};
app.get('/setcookie',(req,res)=>{
    res.cookie('cookietwo','cookie may different',options);
    res.send(`Cookie has been set...`);
});
app.get('/readcookie',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.cookies)
    res.send(req.cookies.cookietwo);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the server sends a cookie to a client, the client might modify the cookie before sending it back to the server in a future request.  Sometimes this is harmless, sometimes it can be required by the application, but sometimes it is important that the cookie sent by the client is unchanged from its original server-defined value.  (Imagine a cookie that contains a username or a bank account number or a monetary amount or a game score.  Tampering with those could breach server security or allow some sort of theft or cheating.)

If the server needs to be able to detect that a cookie has not been changed by the client, the server can include a signature as part of the cookie, along with the actual cookie data that needs to be protected.  The signature is derived from the cookie data and from a secret that is known only to the server.  The secret makes it very difficult for a client that modifies the data to produce the correct signature to go along the modified data.  A cookie with this kind of signature is what the cookie-parser module calls a **signed cookie**.

When a signed cookie is sent back to the server, the server can verify that the signature and the data in the cookie match each other.  If they match then the server can be confident that the data is genuine.  If they don't match then the server knows that the cookie has been modified by the client and the server can reject the request.

So, you would use a signed cookie if you want assurance that the data being returned in the cookie has not been modified by the client.  If the data in the cookie is not valuable and you don't care if it gets modified by the client, or if you have arranged to use some alternative mechanism to validate the contents of the cookie, then you don't need to use a signed cookie.

Note that simply signing cookies does not defend against all of the ways a client might try to trick a server.  In particular, signing does not defend against replay attacks.  Also note that it's a really bad idea for a server to send sensitive data to a client at all.  The example I gave of putting a bank account number into a cookie was just to illustrate the concept.  That's not something that a real web application should do.